# Using Cookies for Session Maintenance gives output Hello72EB80AEBFB7831A35879408414F9ABA

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies

I am making a small program where user's name will be used all over the pages where he navigates. I have written following code.

JSP file:

```
<form action="CookieServletOne" method="post">
User Name:<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Servlet One (under post method):

```
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();

        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        pw.println("Welcome " +username);

        Cookie ck=new Cookie("un",username);
        response.addCookie(ck);

        pw.print("<form action='CookieServletTwo'>"); 
        pw.print("<input type='submit' value='go'>"); 
        pw.print("</form>"); 

        pw.close();
```

Servlet2:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();

    Cookie[] ck=request.getCookies();
    pw.write("Hello" +ck[0].getValue());
```

I want to take the value which is written in text box to the Servlet2 by using cookies. But,

At the end it is printing value something like this:

Hello5BD0268F522455DA719130360F74A969

What I am doing wrong here ???

Server: Apache Tomcat.
Jdk: 1.7
Os: lubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the request has only one cookie, or that the first cookies is the one named "un" that you set? Find YOUR cookie. Don't blindly assume there is just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding below code to your `servlet2` to get your desired result.The output which you are getting is JSESSIONID.

```
Cookie[] ck=request.getCookies();
for(int i=0; i<ck.length; i++) {
    if("un".equals(ck[i].getName())) {
        pw.write("Hello" +ck[i].getValue());
    }
}
```